# Remove 'Fun' as a tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-block-request, meta-tags

Please remove the [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) tag on Stack Overflow. It's a meta tag and isn't really useful in categorizing questions.

[image: Calling Trogdor]

Comment: If I am not wrong, this has been suggested before, but it's been kept alive with the sole purpose to have a quick access to the collection of questions which could be moved to some new SE site sooner or later.

Comment: Yes, we should definitely remove `[fun]`... and bring back `[always-friday-in-iceland]` to replace it.

Comment: @Popular Demand Clarified: Stack Overflow for those that hate to click links.

Comment: What if someone starts up the Fun programming language?

Comment: @Random: Yes! just take **Ook!** and replace Ook. Ook! and Ook? with F U and N. :P

Comment: LOL @ Billy`s comment. Haha...

Comment: If you're really against them I suggest just filtering out the tag

Answer (score 2):

I don't know. I really somehow like those fun questions. I occasionally pass my time at night reading some of them (including that one about the cake for a programmer!)

I'm not supporting them and its a good thing some of those questions have been marked and kept on SO for historical reasons. (I really think the cake question has historical value too, its been deleted I guess)

But I think its what makes us/SO a [fun.community](/questions/tagged/fun.community)