# Should 'fun' tags be purged from SO?

Tags: discussion, tags, off-topic

Based on a conversation that occurred in the comments of this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654617/if-you-were-to-ever-tattoo-yourself-with-a-piece-of-code-what-would-it-be

Would it make sense to purge tags such as [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) [polls](/questions/tagged/polls) [play](/questions/tagged/play) that are no longer on-topic?  These tags exist from the early days of SO before these type of questions were considered off-topic.

Alternatively, is it possible to 'lock' a tag, so as to disallow new posts using that tag, but keep it around retroactively?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83273/remove-fun-as-a-tag

Comment: Why bother, the fun is already gone.

Comment: @mark see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/

Comment: @Jeff, my comment was inspired by one topic that didn't make the cut. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73219/where-is-the-what-code-would-you-have-on-your-wedding-cake-question

Comment: @Mark - I think Jeff's comment from [another issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97283/dont-remove-the-part-of-my-comment/97424#comment-245568) explains it nicely: "we do listen to feedback, but we cannot convert a car into a truck. "This car would be so much better if only it had a big open area in the back for me to haul stuff!" At some point you have to point people towards the truck dealership." There are already plenty of places to discuss silly, pointless, or totally subjective things. That's just not what *these* sites are trying to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, those tags probably should be removed, but I'm reluctant to just have the tags themselves burninated without going through and removing most of the posts themselves.  Just removing the tags feels like treating the symptom without curing the disease.

> Alternatively, is it possible to 'lock' a tag, so as to disallow new posts using that tag, but keep it around retroactively?

I don't think so.  I think we need to remove the tags before unsuspecting new users will be unable to create posts with those meta-tags.  (And hopefully more experienced users won't be tempted to recreate them despite knowing better.)

Comment: The [play] tag appears to be mostly questions about audio playback (and should perhaps be changed to [playback] to discourage misuse), the others have little of any value.

Comment: @bemace: Thanks.  I'll take a look at those to see if any questions need removed before doing a mass retag.  Edit: The `[play]` tag is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Bill:  I think at least [polls](/questions/tagged/polls) and [play](/questions/tagged/play) should be removed as well as their corresponding questions.  Their continued existence is in conflict with Stack Overflow's [stated don't ask policy](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask).  It would improve the quality of the the site.

*It is possible for tags to be blacklisted* -- essentially *locking* users out of posting with them.  However, this is something that's a very sensitive issue and is performed very much in the server backend:  [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list/49418#49418)